# How Can I Delete An Object In a Video Or Picture With Blender?

Tags: masking

I am  trying to delete an object in my video using blender.  I think masking might have something to do with it.  Or I could be wrong.  For example:  I might have a stool with someone sitting on it.  Then in blender I want to get rid of the stool so it looks as if the actor is floating.  Help is appreciated.  Thanks

Note I am talking about live action video being edited in blender

Comment: Many answers already on this site: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/simple-masking-stencil-in-the-vse and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/best-practices-for-masking-image-layers-for-compositing and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14167/how-to-put-a-tracked-model-behind-a-person/14169#14169 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space