# Crop out only a side of a video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, movie-clip-editor

I need to crop out only the left side of a video. Assuming this image is the video, i want to crop out the black side and maintain only the blue part.

[image]

Comment: Instead of black do you need nothing (crop) or transparency (Alpha 0)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Masking/Stencil in the VSE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/simple-masking-stencil-in-the-vse)

Comment: I just edit the question. I need to crop out the black side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you cannot crop (redefine) video size from VSE, since it's globally set in **Dimensions** panel under **Render** Tab. So you have to redefine the Resolution(s) after cropping in VSE to remove stretching effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the strip selected, in the properties panel in `strip input` check `image offset` and `image crop`.

Under `image crop` enter the amount you want to crop to the left box and under `image offset` enter the same number in the x box.

[image]